# Deep learning model comparison

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, overfitting

I have a question regarding my deep learning model, I have trained 2 models with different hyperparameters, the second model got loss results higher than the first model,

first model loss = 0.0047057-best

second model loss = 0.0075174-best

but when it comes to the predictions, the second model predictions are more satisfying and the predictions MAE is lower

does anyone have explanation for this ? as I know the less the loss the better the model, but statistically the second model performs better on the predictions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you reporting the loss on the training data? Or loss on some hold-out data?

Comment: Additionally, you haven’t told us what your loss function is. They may not be comparable between your two models.

Comment: I don’t know what you’re trying to ask here. The model that is performing better is the one with the lower loss, *by definition*.

Comment: Thank you for your  comment, the mentioned loss results above are for training data, the hold-out validation loss as follows

first model = 0.0058104, second model = 0.0083455, and I am using mean-squared error